# SQL insert into with various select multiple rows and fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I need to insert multiple rows and fields in Access 2016 with SQL VBA. I'm doing this thing below -with union -but it doesn't work, it says my sintax with union is wrong. I need to figure out what's wrong otherwise run queries one by one and I have 9 like this!
(EDIT: solution found!)

```
query = "INSERT INTO tblInvoice2 ( Quantity, Price, MMDCarrier) SELECT qryTotals.JRN AS SumOfJRN, qryTotals.[Rate JRN],"
query = query & "qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like " & Me.Combo0 & " union "

query = query & "SELECT qryTotals.MG AS SumOfMG, qryTotals.[Rate MG],"
query = query & "qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like " & Me.Combo0 & ""
```

Here is the answer of what worked, very similar from a code someone showed me below but a differences that changed everything (no error messages and it does insert in the table!). I had to put the selects into a select, still gave me an error and for some reason, when I added the -> as Price and as Quantity it worked. I'm still not sure why it works now, let me know if you have an explanation!

```
query = "INSERT INTO tblInvoice2 ( Quantity, Price, MMDCarrier ) SELECT * FROM (SELECT qryTotals.JRN as Quantity, qryTotals.[Rate JRN] as Price, qryTotals.MMDCarrier FROM qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like '" & Me.Combo0 & "'"
query = query & " UNION SELECT qryTotals.MG , qryTotals.[Rate MG], qryTotals.MMDCarrier From qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like '" & Me.Combo0 & "')"
```

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end (inside the parentheses). You might have other errors too which wouldn't be obvious unless you use parameters.

Comment: what is the value of Me.Combo0?  if there is no single quote on it, then your query will look like this:  where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like <value>.  This has no quotes and will throw an error

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ it doesn't throw an error...I alreay used with a simpler query. really this isn't the issue.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yea didn't see, that I deleted something forgot the comma, but now it's throwing more sinxtaxt errors says im missing an operator

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start implementing parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with unions, you need to put all unions in a subquery, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblInvoice2 ( Quantity, Price, MMDCarrier)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT qryTotals.JRN AS SumOfJRN, qryTotals.[Rate JRN], qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals 
    where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like 'something'
    UNION
    SELECT qryTotals.MG AS SumOfMG, qryTotals.[Rate MG],
    qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like 'somethingElse'
) As A
```

Or, in your VBA implementation:

```vb
query = "INSERT INTO tblInvoice2 ( Quantity, Price, MMDCarrier) SELECT * FROM (SELECT qryTotals.JRN AS SumOfJRN, qryTotals.[Rate JRN],"
query = query & "qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like " & Me.Combo0 & " union "

query = query & "SELECT qryTotals.MG AS SumOfMG, qryTotals.[Rate MG],"
query = query & "qryTotals.MMDCarrier from qryTotals where qryTotals.MMDCarrier like " & Me.Combo0 & ") As A"
```

Note that your query also contains a trailing comma in the `INSERT INTO` part, which isn't a syntax error in Access SQL, but is one in most other forms of SQL, and still is a bad practice. Also, LONG was probably right, you want those single quotes (but really, you should use parameters instead)